# Evaporation time for a Mercury-Ball

Tags: evaporation, laboratory-safety

How long does it take for a Mercury-Sphere to evaporate, if it has a diameter of 1mm and the temperature is 25 Degrees Celsius and the air moves at a speed of 1km/h over it?

What would the formula for this case look like?

I don't just ask out of curiosity but also out of necessity, because I spilled some mercury and probably did not find all of it.

It would be great if you could help! ... :-/

Comment: The first hit from an online search for `evaporation rate mercury` is [this Chemistry Stack Exchange answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/133064).

Comment: In case you don’t read all of the information at the linked answer, it is “too long to ignore.” You should probably get advice from a professional if you have questions. Here is advice for small spills [from the US CDC](https://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/mercury/docs/Residential_Hg_Spill_Cleanup.pdf) and [from the US EPA](https://www.epa.gov/mercury/what-do-if-mercury-thermometer-breaks), including “hotline” phone numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! ... The hotline says, I did everything right and can not do anymore now.

The other thread comes closest with this line of thought: "A ball of 0.1g Hg has a surface of 0.18 cm^2. That leads to an initial loss rate of 9µg/h, 11000h, or a year."

But since the initial loss rate decreases with the decreasing volume, how would the math look like correctly?

Comment: You would integrate—over the total mass—the infinitesimal amount lost per unit time when the sphere is an arbitrary size.

Comment: I found a good scientific paper about this: "The evaporation of a drop of mercury" (https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.1568971). The conclusion: It takes many years to evaporate, but this way the air of the room is only mildly burdened by a single ball of 1mm. If there are more than only very few of these, it gets dangerous.